# when I delete a dependencie from the build.gradle the AppCompat fail

Tags: android, gradle

thats basically what is happening to me, I added a library which I didn't like and know I want to delete it and its makin my app fail 'cause the AppCompat libary don't work after deleting it...

the code:

```
dependencies {
   . 
   .
   .
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

}
```

That's the library that I can't delete if I want my app to work... Otherwise the AppCompat library will fail

In all the clases that import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; it fail and show the following message: "cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show the whole error it gives you

Comment: In all the clases that import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; it fail and show the following message: "cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity"

Comment: I mean the error gradle throws after you remove the compile and press "sync gradle"

Comment: It doesn't say anything, that's the weird thing... the gradle is fine, but the clases I extended from AppCompatActivity throws that message